# Create different instances of a class chain based on a field in the input request with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, instance

Every request that my *Java* application receives, passes through 4 layers:

```
Handler --> Validator --> Processor --> DAO
```

- Handler is the API Resource. (Handler.java)
- Validator validates the input. (Validator.java)
- Processor performs some business logic. (Processor.java)
- DAO is the DB communication layer. (DAO.java)

The input request has a field called the `request_type`. Based on this `request_type`, I want to create different objects for all the layer classes, i.e:

```
request_type_A should pass through Handler1, Validator1, Processor1, DAO1 (instances)
request_type_B should pass through Handler2, Validator2, Processor2, DAO2 (instances)
request_type_C should pass through Handler3, Validator3, Processor3, DAO3 (instances).. and so on
```

To clarify, the requirement is to create different chain of objects for a given request type, so that two request having different `request_type` have entirely different object chain instances. Basically i want to shard my application's object based on a given `request_type`.

I am using *Spring Boot*. Is there a way that spring's `ApplicationContext` can provide different object chains for different object types. Or should I manage these instances by my own?

Is there a way I can create a library which would give me a new object instance for every layer, based on the `request_type` using *Spring*'s `ApplicationContext`?

Or should i create multiple `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: as posted this is not clear. I suggest you provide at least a simple example of what you're trying to achieve with request type A, B and so on (we can't be sure what Handler1/2/3 means etc.

Comment: You should be able to create different child objects using the JsonTypeInfo information. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-polymorphic-type-handling-annotations) for more info on the annotationhttps://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-polymorphic-type-handling-annotations - Basically if `request_type_A` is part of the request body, Jackson can deserialize it as a class `RequestA` and then Spring could find the right controller method to start the chain.

Comment: @dsp_user, Handler1/2/3 are different instances of the handler class i.e every request_type should get a different instance of the same handler class. I need to shard my application's object based on a given request_type.

Comment: @user2565192, I suggest that you post some code. It's possible that what you're trying to do can be accomplished without having to create different instances of the said classes.

Comment: How many possible `request_type` you are expecting here?

Comment: Not dynamic. Most 2-3 in number.

Comment: You can have a Map in each layer, where the key is the request_type, and the Value the class that handles that request. Or you can have a generic interface with a method "canHandle" and use the chain pattern. In the first case, you have a generic method that goes to the map, retrieves the class and invokes whatever it has to invoke. In the second approach, each "layer" should have something like a chain processor and invoke the list of potential processors. With the method "canHandle" each processor check if should handle the request or not. Something like the Filters in Servlets.

Comment: @user2565192 , based on your requirement, I have created sample code on my public git-hub, feel free to refer my answer & verify if it works

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments & question, I understand that you would be receiving 2 or 3 `request_type`.

So main idea which I have used here is to use constructor injection of chained objects with different configuration beans which will be used based on your request type.

Feel free to check-out this simple demonstration based code from github where I have proposed my idea : https://github.com/patilashish312/SpringObjectChaining

So based on this code, I can confirm that

1. This application is not creating chain of object  per request but will re-use if same type of requests received by application
2. Objects assigned to one request type is not being used by other request type.

Below console output is proof :

```
displaying request MyRequest(id=1, name=Ashish, requestType=requestTypeA)
Printing handler bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Handler.MyHandler@31182e0a
Printing validator bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Validator.MyValidator@484e3fe7
Printing processor bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Processor.MyProcessor@70f9b9c7
Printing dao bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Dao.MyDao@2a8175d9
inside dao, doing DAO processing
displaying request MyRequest(id=1, name=Ashish, requestType=requestTypeA)
Printing handler bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Handler.MyHandler@31182e0a
Printing validator bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Validator.MyValidator@484e3fe7
Printing processor bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Processor.MyProcessor@70f9b9c7
Printing dao bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Dao.MyDao@2a8175d9
inside dao, doing DAO processing
displaying request MyRequest(id=1, name=Ashish, requestType=requestTypeB)
Printing handler bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Handler.MyHandler@55ea9008
Printing validator bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Validator.MyValidator@5b2d74c5
Printing processor bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Processor.MyProcessor@5f12fb78
Printing dao bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Dao.MyDao@1a107efe
inside dao, doing DAO processing
displaying request MyRequest(id=1, name=Ashish, requestType=requestTypeB)
Printing handler bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Handler.MyHandler@55ea9008
Printing validator bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Validator.MyValidator@5b2d74c5
Printing processor bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Processor.MyProcessor@5f12fb78
Printing dao bean com.spr.boot3.ConditionalVerification.Dao.MyDao@1a107efe
inside dao, doing DAO processing
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement in my solution.  What I built was a general-purpose command handler, and used a decorator pattern of annotations on each command to provide the specification for which handlers, validators, processors, and dao.

In my implementation, I have API handlers which convert requests to specific commands.  Command class was an subclass of an abstract command class with a generic type param.

API -> all API variables are copied into a wrapper data model. (This could encapsulate the entrypoint of your handler concept or request_type concept)

Command extends AbstractCommand where T is the wrapper data model.

Then I would have an annotation for each of your concepts: Handler, Validator, Processor, Dao.

The general purpose command handler would have a method that "process"es commands by reading their annotations and then lining up the annotation helper that corresponds to that annotation.  This could use the application context to load the bean of the class referenced in the annotation value.  By providing a sequencing property for each of the annotation helpers you could loop over the sorted helpers to perform actions in the right order.

In my implementation this was further augmented by whether or not the command included asynchronous behavior, so that all the synchronous behavior would occur first, and the asychronous behavior would be wrapped in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The beans that are injected in the rest controller don't vary with the http request content. What you can do is factor your *request_type* as a path variable and create the desired chains in separate http mappings like so:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/request_type_A")
    public Object handle1(args...){
        // Validator1 --> Processor1 --> DAO1
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/request_type_B")
    public Object handle2(args...){
        // Validator2 --> Processor2 --> DAO2
    }
```

If this is not practical for whatever reason and you must specify the type dynamically in the *@RequestBody*, *@PathVariable* or *@RequestParam*, then I would suggest implementing a resolver bean similar to this:

```
@Component
public class Resolver {

    private final RequestTypeAValidator requestTypeAValidator;
    private final RequestTypeBValidator requestTypeBValidator;
    
    ...
    
    public IValidator getValidator(String requestType) {
        switch (requestType) {
            case "request_type_A":
                return requestTypeAValidator;
            case "request_type_B":
                return requestTypeBValidator;
            default: 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot find validator");
        }
    }
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it does not comply with the "Open-Closed" principle in the sense that for any new request type, you will need to edit the resolvers. That can be fixed by using a HashMap in the resolver and letting the beans register themselves to that map on @PostConstruct:

```
@Component
public class Resolver {

    private final Map<String, IValidator> validators = new HashMap<>();

    public IValidator getValidator(String requestType) {
        IValidator result = validators.get(requestType);
        if (Objects.isNull(result)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot find validator");
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public void register(String type, IValidator validator) {
        validators.put(type, validator)
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class ValidatorA implements IValidator {

    private final Resolver resolver;

    @PostConstruct
    private void register() {
        resolver.register("request_type_A", this);
    }

    ...
}
```

However, in this approach there is a direct dependency from all implementations back to the *Resolver*.

Lastly, you could inject dynamically like so:

```
@Component
public class Resolver {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    ...

    public IValidator getValidator(String requestType) {
        switch (requestType) {
            case "request_type_A":
                try {
                    return applicationContext.getBean(ValidatorA.class);
                } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
                    // handle exception
                }
            case "request_type_B":
                try {
                    return applicationContext.getBean(ValidatorB.class);
                } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
                    // handle exception
                }
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot find validator");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Avoid taking the client specified string as the class name or type directly in the *applicationContext.getBean()* call. That is not safe and may present a great security vulnerability, use a *switch* or *dictionary* to resolve the correct bean name or bean type.

If you want to inject multiple instances of the same classes, create a configuration class and declare the beans like this:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public IValidator aValidator(){
        return new ValidatorImpl(...);
    }

    @Bean
    public IValidator bValidator(){
        return new ValidatorImpl(...);
    }
}
```

And then to inject it, you can either use the dynamic resolution by name as above, or use the *@Qualifier* annotation:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final IValidator bValidator;

    public MyService(ApplicationContext applicationContext, @Qualifier("bValidator") IValidator bValidator) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.bValidator = bValidator;
    }

    public void getDynamically(){
        IValidator aValidator = (IValidator)applicationContext.getBean("aValidator");
    }
}
```

Comment: But this requires me to create different classes for validators i.e ValidatorA, ValidatorB.. etc i need to create one class but different objects of that class based on request.

Comment: If you use the @Scope("prototype") for the validator component for example it will return a new instance each time it is injected.
Another solution can be declaring multiple beans of the same type that differ by name. Spring will be able to resolve by name using @Qualifier.
If you can provide some code examples of what you want to achieve by those different instances, it would help. Is there a limited number of instances (i.e. one for each request type) or do you want a unique and separate instance for each call?

Comment: Yes there are a limited number of instances (i.e. one for each request type). So each class should have instances for each request type, not for every call. Based on request type the instance should be selected.

Comment: Edited the answer to exemplify how to declare beans of the same class and inject by name.